# objc-mode: Comment-end face is not same face as comment-start

Tags: cc-mode

How can I configure/modify `objc-mode` so that the face of `comment-end` is the same face as `comment-start`?

[The goal is to have `commend-end` always use `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face`, *instead of* `font-lock-comment-face`.  Perhaps whatever method `c-mode` is using to achieve the desired behavior by default can be applied to `objc-mode` as an answer to this question.]

**STEP 1**:  Launch the latest GUI version of Emacs 25 with no user configuration; i.e., `emacs -q`.

**STEP 2**:  Open an Emacs source code file used to build Emacs such as `nsterm.m`.  The buffer will be in `objc-mode`.

**STEP 3**:  Place your cursor on a `comment-start` and type `C-u C-x =` and see that it has `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face`.

**STEP 4**:  Place your cursor on a `comment-end` and type `C-u C-x =` and see that it has `font-lock-comment-face`.

If you repeat this same procedure in a `c-mode` buffer, the `commend-end` delimiter will have `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face`.

Comment: Please consider: (a) showing the problem/effect, (b) posting some code or other explanation of what you are doing to get that effect. (`comment-start|end` is a string - by itself it has no color - maybe clarify what you really mean, here.)

Comment: @Drew -- thanks for the suggestion -- I added a step 1, 2, 3 recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs provides two variables, `comment-start-skip` and `comment-end` which font-lock use to determine which part of a comment should be in `font-lock-comment-face` and which should be in `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face`.

In C and Objective-C mode, `comment-end` are defined differently. (In Objective-C, `comment-start` (which isn't used by font-lock) and `comment-end` are set up for C++-style `//` comments):

C:

comment-start: `"/* "`

comment-end: `" */"`

Objective-C:

comment-start `"// "`

comment-end: `""`

Fortunately, if you define a local `font-lock-comment-end-skip` variable, it will be used instead of `comment-end`.

Effectively, you could get the desired behavior using:

```
(set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-comment-end-skip) "\\*/")
```

See function `font-lock-fontify-syntactically-region` for details.

Comment: The bounty has a 24 hour waiting period before it can be awarded, and stackexchange.com will send me reminders ... Thank you very much!